# Google Play App Store icon rules

Tags: android, image, google-play, app-store, release

I've read the documentation in the Android docs and I know the basic criteria that it needs to fulfill (512x512, high-fidelity, can contain transparency..). But one thing that I don't see anywhere is whether or not the icon needs to be a square image like Apple's app store requirements.  Can anyone who has uploaded an app to the Google Play store confirm?

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule or guideline on Google Play that says the icon must be squared. For example, look at their icon of [My Tracks App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks)